# vim crashes when quitting with a couple of files in buffer

Tags: vim

I identify files with certain characteristics and shoot them into a vim session like ...

`grep -rl '{{[a-z]*}}' | xargs vim`

apart from a warning this works. I have 7 files open in vim. Edit them one by one (using `:w` when finished, `:bn` for going to the next file).

At the end of my session I do `qa` which quits, but freezes the entire bash. I am accessing that server with ssh via a tool named "**R**emote **D**esktop **M**anager".

The edtis seem to be successfull anyway. However i'd prefer not to crash.
Any hint on what I might be doing wrong in the above workflow?

I'd expect that vim closes without freezing the entire bash/ssh session

---

EDIT: I also just noted that there is a `.swp` left in my working dir. It does not give any warning when opening one of the edited files though.

Comment: Use vim's issue tracker (and try to provide that "warning" as it might be of importance).

Comment: I suspect the culprit is in ` | xargs vim` — the terminal (not Bash) freezes because `vim` is a TUI program and its stdin/stdout/stderr shouldn't be redirected from the terminal. Try using `xargs -o vim` to avoid redirects. Try running `reset` on terminal freeze; you have to type it blindly and press `<Enter>`.

Comment: the Warning is: "Input is not from terminal". @phd: spot on. both suggestions do work perfectly (`reset` works after calling it twice though). If you want to put this as an answer I'd be happy to mark it as solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure now the culprit is in `| xargs vim` — the terminal (not Bash) freezes because `vim` is a TUI program and its stdin/stdout/stderr shouldn't be redirected from the terminal.

On an already frozen terminal run `reset`; you have to type it blindly and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> perhaps pressing one <kbd>Enter</kbd> before `reset` to get to the command prompt.

To fix the problem use `xargs -o vim` to avoid redirects. Option `-o`, `--open-tty` redirects stdin from `/dev/tty` thus allowing `vim` to work smoothly.