# Midnight commander opens zip archives with image/PDF viewer instead of listing the contents

Tags: zip, unzip, mc

I am using mc 4.8.27 in Kubuntu 22.04.  My problem is:
When I hit Enter on a zip archive (but not tar or tgz) it opens in the *gwenview* image viewer if there are any images among its contents, and in the *okular* PDF viewer if there are any PDFs but no images. This is utterly bizarre for archives with mixed content and anyway never what I want; I want it to open any archive as a directory listing of its contents.
The view action (F3 in mc) also doesn't work on zip archives; it fails with error messages about bad image or PDF formats.
The entry in the extension file *~/.config/mc/mc.ext* reads

```
# zip
type/^([Zz][Ii][Pp])\ archive
    Open=%cd %p/uzip://
    View=%view{ascii} unzip -v %f
```

So far I have tried:
Set environment variable `MC_XDG_OPEN=/usr/bin/false` - it appears in the mc subshell but makes no change in behavior.
Made the same variable change in */usr/lib/mc/ext.d/archive.sh* and *.../image.sh*, still without effect.
Typing `cd file.zip/uzip://` on the mc command line works as expected but replacing the real file name with the macros %f or %p makes mc core dump, leaving the terminal or tab unusably locked.
My unzip seems to be version 6.0-26.

Edit:
The complete (well, minus the large block of comments at the start) extension file is

```
### GIT Repo ###
# gitfs changeset
regex/^\[git\]
    Open=%cd %p/changesetfs://
    View=%cd %p/patchsetfs://

### Archives ###

# .tgz, .tpz, .tar.gz, .tar.z, .tar.Z, .ipk
regex/\.t([gp]?z|ar\.g?[zZ])$|\.ipk|\.gem$
    Open=%cd %p/utar://
    View=%view{ascii} gzip -dc %f 2>/dev/null | tar tvvf -

regex/\.tar\.bz$
    # Open=%cd %p/utar://
    View=%view{ascii} bzip -dc %f 2>/dev/null | tar tvvf -

regex/\.t(ar\.bz2|bz2?|b2)$
    Open=%cd %p/utar://
    View=%view{ascii} bzip2 -dc %f 2>/dev/null | tar tvvf -

# .tar.lzma, .tlz
regex/\.t(ar\.lzma|lz)$
    Open=%cd %p/utar://
    View=%view{ascii} lzma -dc %f 2>/dev/null | tar tvvf -

# .tar.xz, .txz
regex/\.t(ar\.xz|xz)$
    Open=%cd %p/utar://
    View=%view{ascii} xz -dc %f 2>/dev/null | tar tvvf -

# .tar.F - used in QNX
regex/\.tar\.F$
    # Open=%cd %p/utar://
    View=%view{ascii} freeze -dc %f 2>/dev/null | tar tvvf -

# .qpr/.qpk - QNX Neutrino package installer files
regex/\.(qp[rk])$
    Open=%cd %p/utar://
    View=%view{ascii} gzip -dc %f 2>/dev/null | tar tvvf -

# tar
regex/\.(tar|TAR)$
    Open=%cd %p/utar://
    View=%view{ascii} tar tvvf - < %f

# lha
type/^LHa\ .*archive
    Open=%cd %p/ulha://
    View=%view{ascii} lha l %f

# arj
regex/\.a(rj|[0-9][0-9])$
    Open=%cd %p/uarj://
    View=%view{ascii} unarj l %f

# cab
regex/\.([cC][aA][bB])$
    Open=%cd %p/ucab://
    View=%view{ascii} cabextract -l %f

# ha
regex/\.([Hh][Aa])$
    Open=%cd %p/uha://
    View=%view{ascii} ha lf %f

# rar
regex/\.[rR]([aA][rR]|[0-9][0-9])$
    Open=%cd %p/urar://
    View=%view{ascii} rar v -c- %f

# ALZip
regex/\.(alz|ALZ)$
    Open=%cd %p/ualz://
    View=%view{ascii} unalz -l %f

# cpio
shell/.cpio.Z
    Open=%cd %p/ucpio://
    View=%view{ascii} gzip -dc %f | cpio -itv 2>/dev/null

shell/.cpio.xz
    Open=%cd %p/ucpio://
    View=%view{ascii} xz -dc %f | cpio -itv 2>/dev/null

shell/.cpio.gz
    Open=%cd %p/ucpio://
    View=%view{ascii} gzip -dc %f | cpio -itv 2>/dev/null

shell/.cpio
    Open=%cd %p/ucpio://
    View=%view{ascii} cpio -itv < %f 2>/dev/null

# ls-lR
regex/(^|\.)ls-?lR(\.gz|Z|bz2)$
    Open=%cd %p/lslR://

# patch
regex/\.(diff|patch)(\.bz2)$
    Open=%cd %p/patchfs://
    View=%view{ascii} bzip2 -dc %f 2>/dev/null

regex/\.(diff|patch)(\.(gz|Z))$
    Open=%cd %p/patchfs://
    View=%view{ascii} gzip -dc %f 2>/dev/null

regex/\.(diff|patch)$
    Open=%cd %p/patchfs://
    View=%view{ascii} /bin/cat %f 2>/dev/null

# ar library
regex/\.s?a$
    Open=%cd %p/uar://
    #Open=%view{ascii} ar tv %f
    View=%view{ascii} file %f && nm -C %f

# trpm
regex/\.trpm$
    Open=%cd %p/trpm://
    View=%view{ascii} rpm -qivl --scripts `basename %p .trpm`

# RPM packages (SuSE uses *.spm for source packages)
regex/\.(src\.rpm|spm)$
    Open=%cd %p/rpm://
    View=%view{ascii} if rpm --nosignature --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then RPM="rpm --nosignature" ; else RPM="rpm" ; fi ; $RPM -qivlp --scripts %f

regex/\.rpm$
    Open=%cd %p/rpm://
    View=%view{ascii} if rpm --nosignature --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then RPM="rpm --nosignature" ; else RPM="rpm" ; fi ; $RPM -qivlp --scripts %f

# deb
regex/\.u?deb$
    Open=%cd %p/deb://
    View=%view{ascii} dpkg-deb -I %f && echo && dpkg-deb -c %f

# dpkg
shell/.debd
        Open=%cd %p/debd://
        View=%view{ascii} dpkg -s `echo %p | sed 's/\([0-9a-z.-]*\).*/\1/'`
# apt
shell/.deba
        Open=%cd %p/deba://
        View=%view{ascii} apt-cache show `echo %p | sed 's/\([0-9a-z.-]*\).*/\1/'`

# ISO9660
regex/\.([iI][sS][oO])$
    Open=%cd %p/iso9660://
    View=%view{ascii} isoinfo -l -i %f

# 7zip archives (they are not man pages)
regex/\.(7z|7Z)$
    Open=%cd %p/u7z://
    View=%view{ascii} 7za l %f 2>/dev/null

# Mailboxes
type/^ASCII\ mail\ text
    Open=%cd %p/mailfs://


### Sources ###

# C
shell/.c
    Include=editor

# Fortran
shell/.f
    Include=editor

# Header
regex/\.(h|hpp)$
    Include=editor

# Asm
shell/.s
    Include=editor

# C++
regex/\.(C|cc|cpp)$
    Include=editor

include/editor
    Open=%var{EDITOR:vi} %f

# .so libraries
regex/\.(so|so\.[0-9\.]*)$
    View=%view{ascii} file %f && nm -C -D %f

# Object
type/^ELF
    #Open=%var{PAGER:more} %f
    View=%view{ascii} file %f && nm -C %f

### Documentation ###

# Texinfo
regex/\.(te?xi|texinfo)$

# GNU Info page
type/^Info\ text
    Open=info -f %f

shell/.info
    Open=info -f %f

# Exception: .3gp are video files not manual pages
regex/\.(3[gG][pP])$
    Include=video

# Exception: .264 are special video files not manual pages
regex/\.[hH]?264$
    Open=h264vw %f
    View=(exiftool %f && echo -n "Hit <CR> to return: " && read x)

# Exception: .3mf is a Cura project archive
regex/\.3mf$
    Open=%cd %p/uzip://
    View=%view{ascii} unzip -v %f

# Manual page
regex/(([^0-9]|^[^\.]*)\.([1-9][A-Za-z]*|[ln])|\.man)$
    Open=case %d/%f in */log/*|*/logs/*) cat %f ;; *) { zsoelim %f 2>/dev/null || cat %f; } | nroff -c -Tlatin1 -mandoc ;; esac | %var{PAGER:more}
    View=%view{ascii,nroff} case %d/%f in */log/*|*/logs/*) cat %f ;; *) { zsoelim %f 2>/dev/null || cat %f; } | nroff -c -Tlatin1 -mandoc ;; esac

# Perl pod page
shell/.pod
    Open=pod2man %f | nroff -c -Tlatin1 -mandoc | %var{PAGER:more}
    View=%view{ascii,nroff} pod2man %f | nroff -c -Tlatin1 -mandoc

# Troff with me macros.
# Exception - "read.me" is not a nroff file.
shell/read.me
    Open=
    View=

shell/.me
    Open=nroff -c -Tlatin1 -me %f | %var{PAGER:more}
    View=%view{ascii,nroff} nroff -c -Tlatin1 -me %f

# Troff with ms macros.
shell/.ms
    Open=nroff -c -Tlatin1 -ms %f | %var{PAGER:more}
    View=%view{ascii,nroff} nroff -c -Tlatin1 -ms %f

# Manual page - compressed
regex/([^0-9]|^[^\.]*)\.([1-9][A-Za-z]*|[ln])\.g?[Zz]$
    Open=case %d/%f in */log/*|*/logs/*) gzip -dc %f ;; *) gzip -dc %f | nroff -c -Tlatin1 -mandoc ;; esac | %var{PAGER:more}
    View=%view{ascii,nroff} case %d/%f in */log/*|*/logs/*) gzip -dc %f ;; *) gzip -dc %f | nroff -c -Tlatin1 -mandoc ;; esac

regex/([^0-9]|^[^\.]*)\.([1-9][A-Za-z]*|[ln])\.bz$
    Open=case %d/%f in */log/*|*/logs/*) bzip -dc %f ;; *) bzip -dc %f | nroff -c -Tlatin1 -mandoc ;; esac | %var{PAGER:more}
    View=%view{ascii,nroff} case %d/%f in */log/*|*/logs/*) bzip -dc %f ;; *) bzip -dc %f | nroff -c -Tlatin1 -mandoc ;; esac

regex/([^0-9]|^[^\.]*)\.([1-9][A-Za-z]*|[ln])\.bz2$
    Open=case %d/%f in */log/*|*/logs/*) bzip2 -dc %f ;; *) bzip2 -dc %f | nroff -c -Tlatin1 -mandoc ;; esac | %var{PAGER:more}
    View=%view{ascii,nroff} case %d/%f in */log/*|*/logs/*) bzip2 -dc %f ;; *) bzip2 -dc %f | nroff -c -Tlatin1 -mandoc ;; esac

regex/([^0-9]|^[^\.]*)\.([1-9][A-Za-z]*|[ln])\.lzma$
    Open=case %d/%f in */log/*|*/logs/*) lzma -dc %f ;; *) lzma -dc %f | nroff -c -Tlatin1 -mandoc ;; esac | %var{PAGER:more}
    View=%view{ascii,nroff} case %d/%f in */log/*|*/logs/*) lzma -dc %f ;; *) lzma -dc %f | nroff -c -Tlatin1 -mandoc ;; esac

regex/([^0-9]|^[^\.]*)\.([1-9][A-Za-z]*|[ln])\.xz$
    Open=case %d/%f in */log/*|*/logs/*) xz -dc %f ;; *) xz -dc %f | nroff -c -Tlatin1 -mandoc ;; esac | %var{PAGER:more}
    View=%view{ascii,nroff} case %d/%f in */log/*|*/logs/*) xz -dc %f ;; *) xz -dc %f | nroff -c -Tlatin1 -mandoc ;; esac

# CHM
regex/\.(chm|CHM)$
    Open=which kchmviewer > /dev/null 2>&1 && (kchmviewer %f &) || (xchm %f &)

### Images ###

type/^GIF
    Include=image

type/^JPEG
    Include=image
    View=%view{ascii} identify %f; test -x /usr/bin/exiftool && echo && ( exiftool -s %f ) 2>/dev/null

type/^PC\ bitmap
    Include=image

type/^PNG
    Include=image

type/^TIFF
    Include=image

type/^PBM
    Include=image

type/^PGM
    Include=image

type/^PPM
    Include=image

type/^Netpbm
    Include=image

shell/.xcf
    Open=(gimp %f &)

shell/.xbm
    Open=bitmap %f

shell/.xpm
    Include=image
    View=sxpm %f

shell/.ico
    Include=image

include/image
    Open=(gwenview %f &)
    View=%view{ascii} identify %f
    #View=%view{ascii} asciiview %f

shell/.gpx
    Open=(gpsprune %f &)

shell/.pfs
    Open=(photofilmstrip %f &)
    View=sqlitebrowser %f
    Edit=(sqlitebrowser %f &)


### Sound files ###

regex/\.([wW][aA][vV]|[sS][nN][dD]|[vV][oO][cC]|[aA][uU]|[sS][mM][pP]|[aA][iI][fF][fF]|[sS][nN][dD])$
#       Open=if [ "$DISPLAY" = "" ]; then play %f; else (xmms %f >/dev/null 2>&1 &); fi
#   Open=/usr/bin/mpg123 -K %f
    Open=melt %f
    View=%view{ascii} /usr/bin/soxi %f |sed 1,/Encoding/d

#regex/\.([mM][oO][dD]|[sS]3[mM]|[xX][mM]|[iI][tT]|[mM][tT][mM]|669|[sS][tT][mM]|[uU][lL][tT]|[fF][aA][rR])$
#       Open=mikmod %f
#       #Open=tracker %f
#
#regex/\.([wW][aA][wW]22)$
#       Open=vplay -s 22 %f

regex/\.([mM][pP]3)$
#   Open=if [ "$DISPLAY" = "" ]; then mpg123 %f; else (xmms %f >/dev/null 2>&1 &); fi
#   Open=mpg123 -C %s
#   Open=mpg321 -K %s
    Open=melt %s
    View=%view{ascii} /usr/bin/soxi %f |sed 1,/Encoding/d
#   View=%view{ascii} mpg123 -vtn1 %f 2>&1 | sed -n '/^Title/,/^Comment/p;/^MPEG/,/^Audio/p'

regex/\.([oO][gG][gG|aA|vV|xX])$
#   Open=if [ "$DISPLAY" = "" ]; then ogg123 %f; else (xmms %f >/dev/null 2>&1 &); fi
#   Open=mpg123 -C %f
    Open=melt %s
    View=%view{ascii} /usr/bin/soxi %f |sed 1,/Encoding/d

#regex/\.([sS][pP][xX]|[fF][lL][aA][cC])$
#   Open=if [ "$DISPLAY" = "" ]; then play %f; else (xmms %f >/dev/null 2>&1 &); fi
#
#regex/\.([mM][iI][dD][iI]?|[rR][mM][iI][dD]?)$
#   Open=timidity %f

regex/\.([wW][mM][aA])$
#   Open=mplayer -vo null %f
#   Open=mplayer %f
    Open=melt %f
    View=%view{ascii} mplayer -quiet -slave -frames 0 -vo null -ao null -identify %f 2>/dev/null | tail +13 || file %f


### Play lists ###

regex/\.([mM]3[uU]|[pP][lL][sS])$
    Open=mplayer -vo null %f
#   Open=if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ]; then mplayer -vo null -playlist %f; else (xmms -p %f >/dev/null 2>&1 &); fi

shell/.amz
    Open=clamz %f


### Video ###

shell/REC*.([aA][vV][iI])$
    open=cvlc %f --demux h264 --h264-fps=5 --play-and-exit

regex/\.([aA][vV][iI])$
    Include=video

regex/\.([aA][sS][fFxX])$
    Include=video

regex/\.([dD][iI][vV][xX])$
    Include=video

regex/\.([mM][kK][vV])$
    Include=video

regex/\.([mM][oO][vV]|[qQ][tT])$
    Include=video

regex/\.([mM][pP]4|[mM][pP][eE]?[gG]|[mM]4[vV])$
    Include=video

# MPEG-2 TS container + H.264 codec
regex/\.([mM][tT][sS])$
    Include=video

regex/\.([vV][oO][bB])$
    Include=video

regex/\.([wW][mM][vV])$
    Include=video

regex/\.([fF][lL][iIcCvV])$
    Include=video

regex/\.([oO][gG][mM])$
    Include=video

regex/\.([rR][aA]?[mM])$
    Open=(realplay %f >/dev/null 2>&1 &)

include/video
    Open=(vlc %f >/dev/null 2>&1 &)
    #Open=(dragon %f >/dev/null 2>&1 &)
    #Open=(gtv %f >/dev/null 2>&1 &)
    #Open=(xanim %f >/dev/null 2>&1 &)
    View=(exiftool %f && echo -n "Hit <CR> to return: " && read x)


### Documents ###

# Postscript
type/^PostScript
    Open=(okular -p 1 %f &)
    View=%view{ascii} ps2ascii %f

# PDF
type/^PDF
    #Open=(acroread %f &)
    Open=(okular %f &)
    #Open=(ghostview %f &)
    #Open=(mupdf %f &)
    View=%view{ascii} pdftotext %f -
    Edit=(flpsed %f &)

# The following code very ugly and should not be taken as example.
# It should be cleaned up when the new format of mc.ext is developed.

# html
regex/\.([hH][tT][mM][lL]?)$
    Open=(if test -n "" && test -n "$DISPLAY"; then ( file://%d/%p &) 1>&2; else links %f || elinks -force-html %f || ${PAGER:-more} %f; fi) 2>/dev/null
    View=%view{ascii} links -dump %f 2>/dev/null || w3m -dump %f 2>/dev/null || elinks -dump -force-html %f

# StarOffice 5.2
shell/.sdw
    Open=(libreoffice %f &)

# StarOffice 6 and OpenOffice.org formats
regex/\.(odt|ott|sxw|stw|ods|ots|sxc|stc|odp|otp|sxi|sti|odg|otg|sxd|std|odb|odf|sxm|odm|sxg)$
    Open=(libreoffice %f &)
    View=%view{ascii} odt2txt %f

# AbiWord
shell/.abw
    Open=(abiword %f &)

# Microsoft Word Document
regex/\.([Dd][oO][cCtT][xX]?|[Ww][rR][iI])$
    Open=(libreoffice --writer %f >/dev/null 2>&1 &)
    View=%view{ascii} antiword -t %f || catdoc -w %f || word2x -f text %f - || strings %f
type/^Microsoft\ Word
    Open=(libreoffice --writer %f >/dev/null 2>&1 &)
    View=%view{ascii} antiword -t %f || catdoc -w %f || word2x -f text %f - || strings %f

# RTF document
regex/\.([rR][tT][fF])$
    Open=(libreoffice --writer %f >/dev/null 2>&1 &)

# Microsoft Excel Worksheet
regex/\.([xX][lL][sSwW])$
    Open=(libreoffice --calc %f >/dev/null 2>&1 &)
    View=%view{ascii} xls2csv %f || strings %f
type/^Microsoft\ Excel
    Open=(libreoffice --calc %f >/dev/null 2>&1 &)
    View=%view{ascii} xls2csv %f || strings %f

# Use OpenOffice.org to open any MS Office documents
type/^Microsoft\ Office\ Document
    Open=(libreoffice %f &)
# powerpoint
regex/\.([pP][pP][tT][xX]?)$
    Open=(libreoffice --impress %f >/dev/null 2>&1 &)

# Framemaker
type/^FrameMaker
    Open=fmclient -f %f

# DVI
regex/\.([dD][vV][iI])$
    Open=run-mailcap %f 2>&1 &
    View=%view{ascii} catdvi %f

# TeX
regex/\.([Tt][Ee][Xx])$
    Include=editor

# DjVu
regex/\.(djvu|DJVU)$
    Open=djview %f &

# epub e-books
regex/\.epub
    Open=okular %f &
    View=lsar -l %f

### Miscellaneous ###

# Makefile
regex/[Mm]akefile$
    Open=make -f %f %{Enter parameters}

# Imakefile
shell/Imakefile
    Open=xmkmf -a

# Makefile.PL (MakeMaker)
regex/^Makefile.(PL|pl)$
    Open=%var{PERL:perl} %f

# dbf
regex/\.([dD][bB][fF])$
       Open=%view{ascii} dbview %f
       View=%view{ascii} dbview -b %f

# REXX script
regex/\.(rexx?|cmd)$
       Open=rexx %f %{Enter parameters};echo "Press ENTER";read y

# Disk images for Commodore computers (VIC20, C64, C128)
regex/\.(d64|D64)$
    Open=%cd %p/uc1541://
    View=%view{ascii} c1541 %f -list
    Extract=c1541 %f -extract

# Glade, a user interface designer for GTK+ and GNOME
regex/\.([Gg][Ll][Aa][Dd][Ee])$
    Open=if glade-3 --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then (glade-3 %f >/dev/null 2>&1 &); else (glade-2 %f >/dev/null 2>&1 &); fi

# Gettext Catalogs
shell/.mo
    View=%view{ascii} msgunfmt %f || cat %f

# lyx
regex/\.(lyx|LYX)$
    Open=lyx %f
    View=%view{ascii} lyxcat %f

# torrent
regex/\.([tT][oO][rR][rR][eE][nN][tT])$
    View=%view{ascii} rtorrent -x %f 2>/dev/null

### Plain compressed files ###

# ace
regex/\.(ace|ACE)$
    Open=%cd %p/uace://
    View=%view{ascii} unace l %f
    Extract=unace x %f

# arc
regex/\.(arc|ARC)$
    Open=%cd %p/uarc://
    View=%view{ascii} arc l %f
    Extract=arc x %f '*'
    Extract (with flags)=I=%{Enter any Arc flags:}; if test -n "$I"; then arc x $I %f; fi

# zip
type/^([Zz][Ii][Pp])\ archive
    Open=%cd %p/uzip://
    View=%view{ascii} unzip -v %f

# zoo
regex/\.([Zz][Oo][Oo])$
    Open=%cd %p/uzoo://
    View=%view{ascii} zoo l %f

# gzip
type/^gzip
    Open=gzip -dc %f | %var{PAGER:more}
    View=%view{ascii} gzip -dc %f 2>/dev/null

regex/\.(gz|Z)$
    View=%view{ascii} gzip -dc %f 2>/dev/null

# bzip2
type/^bzip2
    Open=bzip2 -dc %f | %var{PAGER:more}
    View=%view{ascii} bzip2 -dc %f 2>/dev/null

regex/\.bz2?$
    View=%view{ascii} bzip2 -dc %f 2>/dev/null

# bzip
type/^bzip
    Open=bzip -dc %f | %var{PAGER:more}
    View=%view{ascii} bzip -dc %f 2>/dev/null

# compress
type/^compress
    Open=gzip -dc %f | %var{PAGER:more}
    View=%view{ascii} gzip -dc %f 2>/dev/null

# lzma
regex/\.lzma$
    Open=lzma -dc %f | %var{PAGER:more}
    View=%view{ascii} lzma -dc %f 2>/dev/null

# xz
regex/\.xz$
    Open=xz -dc %f | %var{PAGER:more}
    View=%view{ascii} xz -dc %f 2>/dev/null

# MS Windows
shell/\.exe
    Open=wine %f

# Solid modeling
shell/.stl
    View=view-mesh %f &
#   Open=makerware %f &

# Solvespace CAD
shell/.slvs
    Open=solvespace %f &
    View=vim -R %f

# Openscad
shell/.scad
    Open=openscad %f &
    View=%view{ascii} %f

### Default ###

# Default target for anything not described above
default/*
    Open=
    View=
```

Output of *mc -F*:

```
Home directory: /home/s
Profile root directory: /home/s

[System data]
    Config directory: /etc/mc/
    Data directory:   /usr/share/mc/
    File extension handlers: /usr/lib/mc/ext.d/
    VFS plugins and scripts: /usr/lib/mc/
        extfs.d:        /usr/lib/mc/extfs.d/
        fish:           /usr/lib/mc/fish/

[User data]
    Config directory: /home/s/.config/mc/
    Data directory:   /home/s/.local/share/mc/
        skins:          /home/s/.local/share/mc/skins/
        extfs.d:        /home/s/.local/share/mc/extfs.d/
        fish:           /home/s/.local/share/mc/fish/
        mcedit macros:  /home/s/.local/share/mc/mc.macros
        mcedit external macros: /home/s/.local/share/mc/mcedit/macros.d/macro.*
    Cache directory:  /home/s/.cache/mc/
```

Output of *file x.zip*:

```
x.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract, compression method=deflate
```

There is no directory */home/s/.local/share/mc/extfs.d*.

Adding the contents of */usr/lib/mc/extfs.d/uzip* would get me over the max. 30k characters; it is a 482-line Perl script.

Comment: Obviously `mc` doesn't perform the stance you published. Please [edit] and show your entire text of `mc.ext`. Also add the full text output of `mc -F` and `file some.zip`. As for unusably locked terminal — it's not locked, just distorted; [see the hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76113393/7976758) about blindly typing `<Enter>reset<Enter>`.

Comment: Thanks. Everything looks good. Puzzled…